# Issue with generated primary keys when using INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developping an application in JSF 2.0, as DBMS I'm using MySQL.
I'm having an issue with the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement, it generates a new primary key every time a row gets updated. This is the query I'm using.

```
INSERT INTO aanwezigheid_i (jongereId, datum, aanwezig, aankomstTijd, vertrekTijd, alternatiefKamp, redenAfwezig)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE aanwezig = ?, aankomstTijd = ?, vertrekTijd = ?, alternatiefKamp = ?, redenAfwezig = ?
```

The table 'aanwezigheid_i' has got the following columns:

> aanwezigheidId (INT(11), PRIMARY KEY)| jongereId| datum| aanwezig| aankomstTijd| vertrekTijd| alternatiefKamp|  redenAfwezig

If I insert a first row, the primary key 'aanwezigheidId' has got the value 1.
If I UPDATE this first row 10 times and insert a second row afterwards, the primary key value of the second row is 12 and not 2. What am I doing wrong?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE aanwezigheid_i;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not sending **aanwezigheidId** - the primary key - into the `INSERT`, that's why a new row is created. The `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause only takes effect when a record with existing key is inserted.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` key, be aware, that calculating the new `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is done **before** attempting the `INSERT`. If the `INSERT` is converted into an `UPDATE` the new `AUTO_INCREMENT` value is lost.

This is by design, nothing you can do about it, apart from NOT using `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Do you know how I can get the value of the primary key before the insert? I'll need its value to fill in the '?' for 'aanwezigheidId' in the INSERT statement.